# SpringSocial LinkedIn Integration Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I am trying to integrate SpringSocial with a webapp I am building and have been following the instructions [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html).

I have created my @Configuration class (including the ID/key as provided by LinkedIn) and set the configuration to register the ConnectController bean, I then added a button on my web page to connect to linkedIn using the following code:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/connect/linkedin" />" method="POST">
    <button  type="submit">Connect to LinkedIn</button>
</form>
```

When I press the button it succesfully takes me to the LinkedIn authorisation page and identifies my app as requesting authorisation, the problem is, when I press approve I get returned to my application but get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.setInterceptors([Lorg/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:874)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:779)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    ...
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.setInterceptors([Lorg/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;)V
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.ProtectedResourceClientFactory.create(ProtectedResourceClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding.<init>(AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding.java:59)
    at org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.LinkedInTemplate.<init>(LinkedInTemplate.java:65)
    at org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInServiceProvider.getApi(LinkedInServiceProvider.java:38)
    at org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInServiceProvider.getApi(LinkedInServiceProvider.java:27)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth1Connection.initApi(OAuth1Connection.java:94)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth1Connection.<init>(OAuth1Connection.java:56)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth1ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth1ConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectSupport.completeConnection(ConnectSupport.java:115)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth1Callback(ConnectController.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:592)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    ... 67 more
```

Can anyone advise what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like jar version incompatibility. Try using the latest spring (3.1) and the latest spring-social versions.

Comment: I did think it might be that, and already went through my maven exclusions to make sure none of the other spring dependencies were pulling down different versions - but it all seems to be 3.1.0.RC2.. let me go through them again.

Comment: I am now using the 3.1.1.RELEASE version of the Spring libraries, specifically the Spring Web library that contains the RestTemplate and InterceptingHttpAccessor classes. I have checkd in eclipse the and the only version of those classes are the 3.1.1 versions that include the setInterceptor method, but it is still complaining, seems as though Eclipse is doing something strange - any other ideas?

Comment: To update this - it was a JAR incompatability issue, but it was because I was using an older version of the LinkedIn library. I had all the latest Spring/Spring-Social libraries, (the class it was complaining about was in the Spring-Social library, which was the misleading bit)